# Can I download a heap dump to run pprof on later?

Tags: go, pprof

I'm trying to find a way to store the heap data from pprof so that I can share it, view it later, attach to issues and so on. My attempts so far have not worked.

If I run

`go tool pprof http://my-server/debug/pprof/heap` and then run `web`, I get a full graph like I expect. However, If I dowload the file:

`wget -O heapDump http://my-server/debug/pprof/heap`

and try `go tool pprof heapDump`, it seems it can't do everything it needs to. I only get a very limited graph:

[image]

I have tried adding `?debug=1` and playing with different values, but none of them seem to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

`go tool pprof -png http://my-server/debug/pprof/heap > out.png` stores a proper graph for me in the `out.png` file.